# Std::async or std::thread in C++14 best for exceptions handling and concurrency

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, embedded, c++14

There seems a few post on this topic. Basically I want a concurrent worker thread, to manage some heavy duty disk write, will synchronize with main thread using conditional variables and a mutex. Thid is On a multi core system. Std::async seems slightly better option because it will do all exceptions handling, ie will not terminate, with std::thread there is a risk of terminate with exceptions,  unless you use catch try block, which is bit clumsy.

Appreciate any suggestions on this. Somehow std::thread seems more modern way to spawn a thread.
Thanks.

Comment: Will the worker thread *return a value* to the main thread? If not, if it's just a *worker* thread that does some work without an actual single value to return when it's finished, then use an actual thread. The use-case for `std::async` is for a function to calculate a single result that needs to be returned. It's basically a way to call a function in a possibly asynchronous way.

Comment: Thanks, yeh this worker thread is unlike just a function returning a single value, along with main thread, work thread goes thru a reasonably complex shared state machine,  so there is shared info netween the two, managed by condvar and mutex. So I guess for exception handling have to use a try catch block with std::thread Thanks.

Comment: I think it is an even match for this. A still would use std::async because its future is also a good RAII way to synchronize with the shutdown of the background thread. Something that thread misses (You will still need an explicit join call somewhere). All in all std::async is an abstraction on top of a thread. On multicore systems it uses a new thread on linux and a thread from a threadpool on windows (on single core machines it depends, simulated threading or evaluation when std::future's get is called).

Comment: You should get used to try/catch. If an exception occurs and there is no applicable try/catch, it's implementation-defined whether the stack unwinds and destructors are called. This probably won't be an issue for memory or open file cleanup, but it can cause a resource leak if you use RAII to clean up more complicated resources